# Delete/hide 9 out of every 10 rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot find a method to do the following:

Say I have a data set of anywhere between 5-50,000 rows of data output (only ~20ish columns).  I would like to graph this data set but it is quite memory taxing.  Is there a macro to hide 9 out of every 10 rows to essentially cut the dataset down to 10% (more manageable to graph)?  The data is collected every few seconds so I can easily cut out superfluous data without impact to the graph.

I've tried "delete/hide every other row loops" but it still leaves a large amount of information.  I would think a 90% (or, if tunable, an X% cut) would help best.  Thanks for any comments.

Comment: That's a lot of rows.  You may want to summarize the dataset on a different sheet and then create your graph off of the summary data.

Comment: You haven't given us any code to work with -- too broad to answer at this stage. Break it down into a simple, repeatable problem and we'll help you with the answer

Answer (score 1):

This code will randomly select/delete 90% of rows. It might not be exactly 90% because of randomness. Plenty of methods of ensuring exactly 90% but I prefer this for simplicity.

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim inputRange As Range, removeRange As Range, r As Range

    Set inputRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000")

    Randomize
    For Each r In inputRange
        If Rnd < 0.9 Then
            If removeRange Is Nothing Then
                Set removeRange = r
            Else
                Set removeRange = Union(removeRange, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    removeRange.EntireRow.Select
    'removeRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will hide every `x` number of rows in the range. You can assign value of `x` in variable `rowCnt` which is `=9` in the code.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, hideRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, rowCnt As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    rowCnt = 9                              'number of rows to hide
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'change Sheet5 to your data sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data using Column A

        For i = 2 To lastRow Step rowCnt + 1             'loop through Column A starting from Row 2
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i + rowCnt - 1, 1)) 'get range of 9 cells
            Else
                Set hideRng = Union(hideRng, Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i + rowCnt - 1, 1))) 'union range of 9 cells
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    hideRng.EntireRow.Select            'use this line to select rows
    'hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True    'use this line to hide rows
    'hideRng.EntireRow.Delete           'use this line to delete rows
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!